# Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid XML in file /var/www/html/magento/app/code/Bz/Bcs/etc/frontend/routes.xml:

Tags: module, magento2.2.6

While i create a router in magento 2.2.6 module i face the following error

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid XML in file /var/www/html/magento/app/code/Bz/Bcs/etc/frontend/routes.xml:
Element 'config', attribute '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemainstance}noNamespaceSchemaLocation': The attribute '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemainstance}noNamespaceSchemaLocation' is not allowed.
Line: 2

Element 'config': Character content other than whitespace is not allowed because the content type is 'element-only'.
Line: 2

Element 'router': Character content other than whitespace is not allowed because the content type is 'element-only'.
Line: 3

Element 'route': Character content other than whitespace is not allowed because the content type is 'element-only'.
Line: 4

Element 'route': Character content other than whitespace is not allowed because the content type is 'element-only'.
Line: 4

Element 'router': Character content other than whitespace is not allowed because the content type is 'element-only'.
Line: 3
```

My routes.xml code is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemainstance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="blaze" frontName="blazeaccess">
            <module name="Bz_Bcs" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Comment: Have you copied the code from somewhere and pasted into your file?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have added by mistake white space in your routes.xml file

Please check where you added it.

The error says before start each tag like router, route, and module you have white spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code instead of yours:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="blaze" frontName="blazeaccess">
            <module name="Bz_Bcs" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```